# Are basecamp resources ID unique?

Tags: basecamp

I found a couple references but quite very old and I know the API has changed since.

Are all resources IDs **globally** unique (across all accounts)?

For instance are all to-do item IDs unique accross all accounts in the system ?

I want to know as i would like associate data with a to-do ID and i want to make sure to avoid collisions (as unlikely as they could be)

**EDIT:** 
Here is a sample ID: 8549954
One of the post i referred to: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/37signals-api/ID$20unique/37signals-api/cNm-HKZ5fQY/xi497xpem1AJ
Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What do the IDs look like? If they are GUID values I would assume they are unique, or at least intended to be unique. If the are simple ID numbers (e.g 1, 2, 3) then I would guess they are not

Comment: That's the thing they are just an interger, quite a big one but sitll. Tho post from 3~4 years ago seems to suggest that they are unique

Comment: Can you give an example of an ID? And what post are you referring to?

Comment: Having looking at the API documentation (and your edit) I would say they are unique. Those ID numbers are way too large to be unique only to a single account. No way a single account would have as many as `8549954` todo items. OF course this is all best guess as there doesn't seem to be anything in the docs that specifically confirms it

Comment: well this is a to-do item, so i am guessing there are way more than that in their databases

Comment: maybe, but there definitely isn't that many in your single account right? I would say it could be they only have that many. I would imagine that not all customers use basecamp to its full potential so many probably dont even use TODO lists

Comment: No I think they all do, but yeah IDs are probably unique, they somehow must be deleting old todos and reseting the counts or smt .. Hopefully someone form basecamp support can confirm that. Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: I doubt you will get anyone from basecamp support on here... you would be better off contacting them directly and then posting your own answer to relay what they say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are unique across accounts, within the same product.  So, for all requests to the Basecamp API (https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api), you can treat the resource IDs as unique.

Comment: Cool, sorry for the double post I was not sure I'd hear form you guys here. So i can safely use a to-do ID as a unique ID as long as i am dealing with the same product.Thanks